# Column cannot be null Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `physicians` (
  `physician_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `physician_gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `physician_dob_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `physician_dob_month` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `physician_dob_year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `physician_profession` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `medical_specialty` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `medical_school` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `traning_year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `physician_minc` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `physician_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `physician_state` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `physician_city` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `physician_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `physician_postal_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `physician_phone_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `physician_default_msg` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`physician_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

I am executing a query and it showing me column can not be null  below is my query

```
INSERT INTO `physicians` (`user_id`, `physician_gender`, `physician_dob_date`, `physician_dob_month`, `physician_dob_year`, `physician_profession`, `medical_specialty`, `medical_school`, `traning_year`, `physician_minc`, `physician_country`, `physician_state`, `physician_city`, `physician_address`, `physician_postal_code`, `physician_phone_number`, `physician_default_msg`) VALUES (4, 'Female', '5', '7', '1955', '3', '2', '1', '1965', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

**Error - Column 'physician_minc' cannot be null**

`physician_minc` is not mandatory field. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: For all columns you have as NOT NULL, you have to specify values (or have default values.)

Comment: If you want to allow null's, simply skip the `NOT NULL`.

Comment: How can we define a column Null ?

Comment: Read my previous comment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have defined the not null value to 'physician_minc':

```
`physician_minc` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
```

How can you pass the null value to it.First you need to make the `physician_minc` column as null then only you can pass your desired null value.

```
`physician_minc` varchar(20) NULL,
```

Comment: How can we define a column Null ?

Comment: UPDATE table SET field = NULL WHERE something = something

Comment: Or you can also do the same in phpmyadmin by ticking the null field in structure

Comment: Welcome.If it really helps then you can upvote and right tick my answer.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't define physician_minc as `not null`

Comment: How can we define a column Null ?

Answer (score 2):

`` ALTER TABLE physicians CHANGE `physician_minc` `physician_minc` VARCHAR(20) NULL; ``

Answer (score 2):

When you create your table you define a columns as mandatory with NOT NULL. You should change all columns which are not mandatory to NULL instead.

For your insert code I assume only the first 10 fields are mandatory so to correctly insert your data your table generating code should be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `physicians` (
 `physician_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `physician_gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `physician_dob_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `physician_dob_month` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `physician_dob_year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `physician_profession` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `medical_specialty` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `medical_school` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `traning_year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `physician_minc` varchar(20) NULL,
  `physician_country` varchar(100) NULL,
  `physician_state` varchar(60)  NULL,
  `physician_city` varchar(60) NULL,
  `physician_address` varchar(100)  NULL,
  `physician_postal_code` varchar(10)  NULL,
  `physician_phone_number` varchar(20)  NULL,
  `physician_default_msg` longtext  NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`physician_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The last values of your insertion are NULL yet declared as not null in the table creation, hence the error.
If physician_minc is not mandatory then allow it to be NULL in the table creation by replacing   `physician_minc` varchar(20) NOT NULL, into   `physician_minc` varchar(20) NULL,

Comment: How can we define a column Null ?

Comment: NOT NULL is an extra constraint to the table you are imposing. ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to enter a value simply don't make the column not null, skip this statement, else it is compalsary to enter a value in it.

Answer (score 1):

Update your table as this:

```
ALTER TABLE `physicians` 
CHANGE `physician_minc` `physician_minc` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER 
SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike your query this query will substitute an empty string for null if the columns do not support null values.:

```
INSERT INTO `physicians` (`user_id`, `physician_gender`, `physician_dob_date`, `physician_dob_month`, `physician_dob_year`, `physician_profession`, `medical_specialty`, `medical_school`, `traning_year`, `physician_minc`, `physician_country`, `physician_state`, `physician_city`, `physician_address`, `physician_postal_code`, `physician_phone_number`, `physician_default_msg`) SELECT 4, 'Female', '5', '7', '1955', '3', '2', '1', '1965', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL;
```