# codeigniter rest api doesn't work on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-3

I have a codeigniter api that worked on my local machine. All functions worked fine.
But when I uploaded the project to server it started to cause problem. The get requests are ok. But problem is on the put,post and delete request.
The project is working fine. The problem is in the api.

here's my rest controller

```
    function customer_put(){
    $this->load->model('registration_model');
    $ids = $this->registration_model->last_id_customer();
    foreach ($ids as $id){

    }

    $last_id = ($id->id)+1;
    $cus_id = 'cus-'.$last_id;


    $cus_name = $this->put('name');
    $cus_father_name = $this->put('father_name');
    $cus_address = $this->put('address');
    $cus_password = $this->put('password');
    $nid = $this->put('nid');
    $purpose = $this->put('purpose');
    $avg_jar = $this->put('avg_jar');
    $order_type = $this->put('order_type_id');
    $staff_id = $this->put('staff_id');


    $create = $this->registration_model->customer_reg_api($cus_id,$cus_name,$cus_password,$cus_father_name,$cus_address,$nid,$purpose,$avg_jar,$order_type,$staff_id);
    if($create){
        $message = array(
            'Message'=>'Customer created',
            'customer_id'=>$cus_id
        );
        $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
    } else {
        $this->response('Customer creation failed',REST_Controller::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

}
```

the error shows like this in postman

```
        <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1048</p>
        <p>Column 'order_type_id' cannot be null</p>
        <p>INSERT INTO `customer` (`cus_id`, `name`, `password`, `father_name`, `address`, `nid`, `purpose`, `avg_jar`, `order_type_id`, `staff_id`) VALUES ('cus-10', NULL, 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)</p>
        <p>Filename: models/Registration_model.php</p>
        <p>Line Number: 114</p>
```

i sent data in the body by postman. don't know where is the problem.

Comment: `Column 'order_type_id' cannot be null`: I'm not sure what exactly is unclear about this? I assume this column definition for `order_type_id` has `NOT NULL` and you're trying to set it to `NULL`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column cannot be null Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698167/column-cannot-be-null-mysql)

Comment: Check `var_dump($this->input->input_stream())exit;` because it seems your PUT request array is empty. Read [here more info](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) related.

Comment: the problem is that the data was not passing from the body of the response. after an hour it worked. perhaps i made some mistakes that's why it wasn't working. Thanks you people for your replays

Comment: Also, it would be good and less expensive having `cus_id` AUTO_INCREMENT field to leave it populates itself automatically.